# `dotnet --list-sdks` does not see the installed sdk on Mac. Why?

Tags: .net, macos, installation, terminal, sdk

I downloaded the .NET SDK from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/5.0)

[image]

then I just run the downloaded file and it seems I got everything installed.

[image]

[image]

But whenever I run the `dotnet --list-sdks` I am not getting the installed .NET SDK in the list.

[image]

Could someone help me understand what am I missing here, please?

Comment: Did you open the terminal after installation?

Comment: @Eldar, yes I tried it all after the installation.

Comment: I have the same problem, but with version 6.0.100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of the issue in my case was that I have a Mac on the M1 chip. The M1 chip does not see any SDK below the .NET 6.